# Where are menu command shortcuts stored for Firefox and Thunderbird, e.g. ALT_F for main menu entry "File"?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox, thunderbird, keyboard-accelerators

I'd like to harmonize keyboard-accelerators for main menu entries of Firefox and Thunderbird, maybe add some (if it possible will be seen).
The standard localization for German setup is a little bit inconsistant, sometimes letters are used twice/redundantly, sometimes new versions change them w/o being required, too.
(E.g. I found /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/muffin.mo where I change the Cinnamon shortcuts to maximize/minimize windows after each update so the spine controlled finger moves don't make me mad - I have to work with Windows all day long.)
So where do I find these files? I won't mind if they are somehow compiled or compressed.

Comment: you could possibly try making a custom keyboard shortcut for Ubuntu, then make a script  and xdotool mousemove and click or send the menu keys . awkard though, xdotool windowactivate your app.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if all of this were more configurable, but I am afraid that for these Mozilla products (similar to many other software) editing source code and recompiling may be the only way to customize these menu accelerator keys.

I know, but I believe a disappointing answer is better than no answer. The hope still remains that someone capable of explaining an approach may come along.